# zip code to barcode with check digit

Tags: c++

I have to write a program that has the user input a zipcode and output a bar code with a check digit. I am able to get the program to print the correct bar code but am not sure get the program to print the bar code with the postal code for the result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

string Bar_Code(char digit)


 /* Write a program that asks the user for a zip code and prints the 
bar code. Use : for half bars, | for full bars.*/
 {
     if (digit == '0' ){
     return "||:::";
     else if (digit == '1')
     return ":::||";
     else if (digit == '2')
     return "::|:|";
     else if (digit == '3')
     return "::||:";
     else if (digit == '4')
     return ":|::|";
     else if (digit == '5')
     return ":|:|:";
     else if (digit == '6')
     return ":||::";
     else if (digit == '7')
     return "|:::|";
     else if (digit == '8')
     return "|::|:";
     else if (digit == '9')
     return "|:|::";
     else
     return "Invalid";

}


string user_input;
string result = "";
int digits[5];
int sum = 0;

cout << "Enter zipcode and the check digit: ";
    /* check digit is the sum of all the digits + check digit to make 
 the sum a multiple of 10 */
cin >> user_input;

for(int i=0; i < user_input.length();i++)
{
     digit[i] = user_input[i] - '0';
    string current_barcode = Bar_Code(user_input[i]);
    result += current_barcode;
    sum += digits[i];
}
     int remainder = sum % 10;
     int checkDigit = 10 - remainder;

     result += Bar_Code(checkDigit + '0');

     cout << checkDigit << endl;

     cout << endl;

     return 0;

  }
```

Comment: If you're referring to the ZIP Code used by the US Postal Service (USPS), then a) your bar code isn't valid (you can purchase a bar code symbol font or library to generate the valid barcode), and b) the bar code doesn't get *added* to the ZIP Code - it gets printed just above the bottom edge of the envelope or label, and the USPS has information about where that should be located on their web site.

Comment: Meant to say not sure how to add barcode with check digit to get result

Comment: You calculate the checkdigit and add it to the end of the barcode. The algorithm to calculate it is explained in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSTNET). If you're trying to create an actual accurate barcode, you'll need to update to the [Intelligent Mail format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Mail_barcode), which is entirely different and doesn't implement a check digit.

Comment: I have the algorithm for solving the check digit but the program will only print the barcode not including the check digit

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Get the full input, calculate the check digit and append it, and then print the entire string. You should not be calling `Bar_Code` more than once, and you should have a separate function that accepts the entire bar code and calculates the check digit.